# SQL Query to run a select query Soccer league table

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

Here is my query. I have a colomun name "Played" (int). I update it as one if a match is played. so sum it later. Now i want number of matches played by a team to this query. But I have no idea how to add that.

```
Select  DENSE_RANK() OVER(order by Point DESC,GD DESC) as Rank, * from (select  TName, Sum(Score) as Score, Sum(GA) as GA,Sum(Diff) as GD,Sum(Point) as Point from  (Select f.teamID,Score as Score, GA as GA,Score-GA as DIff,
case 
when Result = 'W' then 3
when Result = 'D' then 1
Else 0
end as Point, T.TName, 
from Fixtures F
inner join  Teams T on t.TeamID = f.TeamID  ) S
group by teamID,TName) SS
order by Point DESC,GD DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Do a count on result. That would get how many games they played

Comment: Within your select stament, count(result) as gamesplayed

Comment: There are nested select statements. I've tried it every where. But still throws an error!! :(

Comment: Column 'Fixtures.TeamID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause

Comment: Include it in the group by clause

Comment: I'm unable to do that. Please help me.